# How to base dependency injection on an argument

Tags: blazor

I need to base my dependency injection on an argument (the string "tranArg" in this case). For now, the argument is hard-coded in. Nestled in my other injections, I have this:

```
@{if(tranArg == "apin"){
        @inject Csla.Blazor.ViewModel<FezWeb.BizObj.AP_APIN> vm
    }
    else if(tranArg == "arin"){
        @inject Csla.Blazor.ViewModel<FezWeb.BizObj.AR_ARIN> vm
    }
}
```

When I attempt to use "vm," it is always as if only the second inject statement were there without any of the logic. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Automatic injection uses attributes which are assigned at compiletime not during runtime, so you can't do it the way you've shown.

You need to do the assignment at runtime by setting up the services manually in `OnInitialized`.

First you need to define an interface that both the view models implement.  I've used the `WeatherForecastService` here

```cs
    public interface IWeatherForecastService
    {
        public Task<WeatherForecast[]> GetForecastAsync(DateOnly startDate);
    }
```

And the actual service implemenents the interface:

```
    public class WeatherForecastService :IWeatherForecastService
    {
      //...
    }
```

```
    public class AnotherWeatherForecastService :IWeatherForecastService
    {
      //...
    }
```

You can then implement your service selection like this by injecting and then using the `IServiceProvider`.

```cs
@page "/"
@inject IServiceProvider _serviceProvider

//...
@code {
    private IWeatherForecastService _service = default!;
    private bool _test = true;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
       _service = _test 
            ? _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<WeatherForecastService>()
            : _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<AnotherWeatherForecastService>();
    }

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this sounds as if you are looking for a factory, the DI of Blazor cannot register objects by key. Instead of injecting the ViewModel itself you would then inject the factory which can get or create the correct ViewModel:

```
@inject IViewModelService ViewModelService

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        ViewModel = ViewModelService.Get(tranArg);
    }

    private IViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

A difficulty is, that you want to create *generic* ViewModels. So depending on the parameter, you would get two totally different types, the binding requires the type of the ViewModel at design time though. One way out is to implement a common interface to your generic ViewModels, this may or may not be a solution for you, because you will loose the advantage of the generic approach.